# Antisymmetry and coordinate invariance

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, symmetry, coordinate-systems, pauli-exclusion-principle

I have always been confused about the antisymmetry of the wave function for fermions.
Suppose we have  a wave function such $\psi$ such that
$$\psi(x_1,x_2)=-\psi(x_2,x_1)\tag{1}$$

Now suppose we have coordinate transformation $f_1,f_2$ such that we have

$$\psi(x_1,x_2)= \psi(f_1(y_1,y_1),f_2(y_1,y_2))=\phi(y_1,y_2)\tag{2}$$

How can we prove that

$$\phi(y_1,y_2)=-\phi(y_2,y_1)~?\tag{3}$$

Comment: It's worth being careful about trying to physically interpret the mathematics too literally. The wave function is not a real thing, it is a mathematical object which we have to *assign* to something physical that we can measure.

Comment: is $x_1-x_2$ the same as $x_2-x_1$, even if the coordinates are imaginations of our mind?

Comment: Comment to the post (v4): Consider to double-check eq. (2) for typos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can we prove that $\phi(y_1,y_2) = -\phi(y_2,y_1)$?

You cannot. Consider
$$f_1(y_1,y_2) = \frac{1}{2}(y_1 + y_2),\qquad f_2(y_1,y_2) = \frac{1}{2}(y_1 - y_2).$$
Then, let us take $x_2=0$. In general, $\psi(x_1,0)\neq 0$. We have
$$\phi(x_1,x_1) = \psi(x_1,0) \neq 0.$$

The crucial point is that, in the definition of $\psi(x_1,x_2)$, $x_1$ and $x_2$ denote positions of two identical fermions, and this is the reason for $\psi$ to be antisymmetric under the $x_1\leftrightarrow x_2$ transformation.

After the coordinate transformation, $y_1$ and $y_2$ do not necessarily correspond to positions of two fermions. In particular, interchanging the positions of the two fermions doesn't mean that $y_1$ becomes $y_2$ and vice versa. Hence, there is no reason for $\phi$ to be antisymmetric under $y_1\leftrightarrow y_2$.

Answer (score 1):

By your logic you should get 
$$
f(y,z) = -f(z,y) \tag{1}
$$
In any case, the wavefunction under particle interchange is antisymmetric, the individual electrons are identical. Their properties remain the same. We've only interchanged them, not altered them.